# Animation Rendering Blank

Tags: rendering

I just started using blender today so I could make a simple animation with a logo that I recently created. With the help of Google, I've manages to get the animation working the way I wanted, but when I go to render, it renders blank. When I open the video file, it is just a black screen.

I've tinkered with a handful of the settings but can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Like I mentioned, this is my first time using Blender, so I'm hoping it is simply a box that I failed to check or something simple like that.

I've attached screenshots that I hope will be helpful, but let me know if you need more information.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated as it has been a slow process getting things figured out. lol

Thanks!

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]